# Overwriting Excel columns instead of creating a new one

Tags: java

I have written a program that takes .pdf files and writes certain data from pdf into columns of an excel sheet.

I am having trouble figuring out a bug that, when multiple .pdfs are selected, it fills all columns with only the final pdf selected.

I.E: 3 pdfs selected(a, b, c): excel created has 3 columns all with the appropriate data from pdf c.

where I am looking for this:

```
|column 1|column 2 |column 3|

|data a  |  data b |  data c|
```

I think there is a problem with my over complicated looping structure.

This is my first program and the code is a bit messy but here is a snippet:

```
String[] listString = (String[]) list.toArray(new String[0]); 
String[] ionString = (String[]) Ion.toArray(new String[0]);

FileInputStream template = new FileInputStream(new File(templatePath));

HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(template);
HSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

int totalRowNum = worksheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
System.out.println("Last row at: " + totalRowNum);

for (int r = 0; r < totalRowNum; r++) { // check each row
 Row rw = worksheet.getRow(r);
 System.out.println("Row Number: " + (r + 1));
 if (rw == null) {
  System.out.println("Row ERROR");
  continue;
 }
 System.out.println("No Row erros: Line 693");
 for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) { //check each cell

  Cell c = rw.getCell(x);

  if (c == null) { //if cell is null, make it Blank
   c = rw.getCell(x, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
   System.out.println("Converting Null cells to Blank");
  }

  System.out.println("No Cell Erros: Line 699");

  if (c.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) { //if cell is blank
   System.out.println("No more Null Cells");
   for (int n = 1; n < size + 1; n++) { //fill blank cell
    int i = 0;
    System.out.println("Line 705, Should be populating");

    //fills each cell n with string from String array index i
    HSSFCell cellB1 = name.createCell((short) n);
    cellB1.setCellValue(listString[i]);
    i++;
    /**  ..... a bunch of these for each cell ..... **/
   }
  }
 }
}
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(templatePath);
```

//above outputStream writes over the template

```
System.out.println("Your file is located at: " + templatePath);
workbook.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
System.out.println("*************COMPLETE*************");
}
```

As requested, here is where I am getting my listString from:

First from JavaFX:

```
private List<File> showMultipleFileChooser() throws FileNotFoundException {

    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.setTitle("Select PDF files"); 

    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll( 
        new ExtensionFilter("PDF Files", "*.pdf"));
    List<File> selectedFiles = fileChooser.showOpenMultipleDialog(savedStage);
     // List of files selected


    if (selectedFiles !=null){     //if files are selected
                  for (int i = 0; i < selectedFiles.size(); i++){
                      String fPath = selectedFiles.get(i).toString(); 
                              //gets file path in String format 
                      int size = selectedFiles.size();
                      System.out.println("LOOK AT ME " + fPath);
                      PDFTest.pdfTotxt(fPath, size, templatePath);
                  }  
            }
```

Then after converting into a .csv and using  CSVParser:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); //creates ArrayList<String>
List<String> Ion = new ArrayList<String>();

FileResource csv = new FileResource ("C:\\PDFTester\\CSV.csv"); 
//pdf has already been converted to .csv named CSV.csv

CSVParser parser = csv.getCSVParser(false); //Parses CSV
for (CSVRecord record : parser) {

    a = record.get(0);
    if (a.contains("Material:")){    //if index 0 is the one i'm looking for
       System.out.println(a + " " + record.get(1));
       material = record.get(1); 
//saves the data from that line into global String named material

       Ion.add(record.get(0));
       list.add(material); //adds data i want into List<String> list
     }
  //A bunch more like this...
```

Comment: Hello Pdatric  You show the code to write to the excel file. However I do not see where you are getting the input. Where is listString defined? What does it contain? I do not see a definition for it... i.e. the code may be messy yes... but it is also incomplete. As you said the problem is that it only prints the last pdf. Then show where you are doing this.

Comment: Edited showing where the listString is coming from.

in words:
1) using JavaFX: select multiple .pdf files 
   a) these files are saved using List<File> selectedFiles = fileChooser.showOpenMultipleDialog(savedStage);
2) loop over each .pdf file in my List
  a) each file is converted from a .pdf --> .txt --> .csv
  b) each .csv is parsed using a CSVParser and the data is saved into an ArrayList<String> by index and named listString.

Comment: I should also add that, when I print the listString, I see the correct data that correlates to the correct .pdf for each iteration of the program. It is then overwriting the already completed columns.

I.E if I run it on 3 pdfs (a, b, c), The console output shows that a populates the excel, then b populates the excel, then c populates the excel. 

I then find that c overwrote both a and b.

Comment: If that is true... then I would look closely at how you are writing the data to excel. I will focus there also from what you just told me. I will assume the data is correct in the listString array.

Comment: Thanks JohnG,

Just by your recomendation to look more closely at the writing data to the excel I have fixed it.

In my final loop that was for (int n = 1; n < size+1; n++) {   that set each column number to write the data to, it was running inside the loop for each file.

I fixed this by declaring n as a global int variable set to 1(for column 2, where I want data to start) and at the end of each iteration through populating the cells I would add 1 to n so n++;

This changes the global variable and forces the data into the next cell over that is blank.